# How to display XML RSS feeds in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, rss

I've been doing countless hours of research on RSS feeds and I have found nothing that will suit my needs. I have been working on a site to basically hone my skills as an apprentice programmer and one thing I need to implement is a news feed.

How can I create a news feed that can be customized, as in how it is displayed on a webpage? What I want to do specifically is have 3 columns, with 3 news posts per row, and each post being displayed in chronological order. I was thinking that this could be done with an html table, where I can use javascript to take the data from the XML file and put it into the table, however I could not come up with a solution that would do this, which is the reason why I am here.

I do not expect anyone to do this for me, I just want to know if anyone has either done something like this before, or if there is a simpler way to do this, or if I am not doing this correctly at all.

**I do not want to use an RSS service that requires me to pay a subscription, or that does not allow me to fully customize the feed, in case anyone gives me a link to one (such as rssinclude)**

---

#### Solved

Figured this out a while back, I built my own xml parser starting with javascript, but moved to php when I needed a different method to call rss feeds from different domains. Here is the bit where I parsed the passed xml, there is a lot more code that is unrelated to the topic so there are some random variables in there:

```
$content = file_get_contents($cache);
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
$item = $x->channel->item;
echo '<tr>';
for($i = $xmn; $i < $xmx; $i++) {
    echo '<td class="item"><p class="title clear">' . 
        $item[$i]->title . 
        '</p><p class="desc">' . 
        $desc=substr($item[$i]->description, 0, 250) . 
        '... <a href="' . 
        $item[$i]->link . 
        '" target="_blank">more</a></p><p class="date">' . 
        $item[$i]->pubDate . 
        '</p></td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

And here is the bit where I request the php file and take the resultant text to place it in my html:

```
function ajax(url, xmn){
        var dataString = [url, xmn],
            jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);
            request = $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(){
                    if(request != null){
                        request.abort();
                        
                    }
                },
                type: "POST",
                url: "/scripts/feed.php",
                data: {jsonString : jsonString}, 
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    document.getElementById('rss').innerHTML = result;
                },
            });
```

Comment: use yql to get the the data, mustache for the databinding, bootstrap for the grid layout.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info, ill check it all out tomorrow and let you know how it goes =D

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create XSL stylesheets for the various output formats.

Comment: Right, I figured this out long ago but forgot about this old post, I didn't need XSL, I built my own xml parser that displays it in my site.